# Convert nested html into JSON

Tags: jquery, html, json, serialization, dictionary

I have some html whose structure looks something like

```
<div><input></input>
  <div><input></input>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div><input></input>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div><input></input>
  <div><input></input>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to convert it to something like (v for each input value and t for the input type)

```
[{'value': v, 'type': t, children : [{'value': v, 'type': t, children : [ etc....
```

I suspect I can do this easily with a jQuery map, but not sure how

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: i have a nested structure which I want to represent in my json. I will then be able to easily populate my relational database with the correct parent child relationships